# Animation not starting the first time even when started in Handler.post()

Tags: android

I have a fragment where in `onCreateDialog()` I start a background thread, which eventually calls this method:

```
protected void showMessageWithProgressWhenEmpty(final String message) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        textView.setText(message);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            R.drawable.anim_spin_refresh, 0, 0, 0
        );
        AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable)textView.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
        anim.start();
    }
}
```

The `handler` is created in `onCreateDialog()`. Subsequent calls to `showMessageWithProgressWhenEmpty()` animate like intended. The first call to this method (the one that doesn't animate properly) happens within about 1 second of the call to `onCreateDialog()`.

I have already seen answers that mention that animations won't work when started in `Activity.onCreate()`, which is why I'm `post`ing the call to the `handler`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Had some problems with animations before, not the same exact issue you have, but I had to invalidate the view.

Try invalidate() after the setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds and after the start methods.

Comment: I tried to call `invalidate()` after `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` as well as after `anim.start()` with no effect. Any other ideas?

Comment: textView.startAnimation( anim ) ? , just guessing.  Although this looks like you are trying to start an animation before the view is actually "created".  Probably looking for a function like onStart in your DialogFragment , instead of onCreateDialog that you are using now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protected void showMessageWithProgressWhenEmpty(final String message) {

        textView.setText(message);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
            R.drawable.anim_spin_refresh, 0, 0, 0
        );
        AnimationDrawable anim = (AnimationDrawable)textView.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
       // run the start() method later on the UI thread
        textView.post(new Starter());
}
 class Starter implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            anim.start();
        }
```

Call starter after set your text view

Comment: This is in a fragment, so it doesn't have this method. Is there a similar method I can use?